# implicit declaration of function 'getaddrinfo' on Windows with Mingw

Tags: c, windows

I'm trying to create a really basic client application, based on the code on msdn but i get the error in the title.
Here is the complete code:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#define DEBUG 1


#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "9001"

void CreateSocket();
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    CreateSocket();


    return 0;
}


void CreateSocket()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    *ptr = NULL,
                    hints;
    char *sendbuf = "this is a test";
    int iResult;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);

    ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );    

    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    iResult = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, 
            ptr->ai_protocol);

    iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);

    freeaddrinfo(result);
    iResult = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );

    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

}
```

I'm on Windows 10, with MinGW.
This the complete compile and error:

```
gcc -Wall -o "test" "test.c" -lws2_32 (nel direttorio: C:\Users\FedericoPonzi\Google Drive\Programmazione\C\ProgrammazioneDiSistema\FedericoPonzi-programmazionedisistema-40c332bcd001\FedericoPonzi-programmazionedisistema-40c332bcd001\Prove)
test.c:10:0: warning: ignoring #pragma comment  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
 ^
test.c: In function 'CreateSocket':
test.c:46:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getaddrinfo' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  iResult = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
  ^
test.c:52:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'freeaddrinfo' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  freeaddrinfo(result);
  ^
test.c:35:6: warning: variable 'iResult' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  int iResult;
      ^
C:\Users\FEDERI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAW2c9I.o:test.c:(.text+0xbb): undefined reference to `getaddrinfo'
C:\Users\FEDERI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAW2c9I.o:test.c:(.text+0x11b): undefined reference to `freeaddrinfo'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\FEDERI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAW2c9I.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in section `.eh_frame'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Compilazione fallita.
```

I'm using Geany as IDE.

Also: why do i get the "ignoring pragma" error? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About

> warning: ignoring #pragma comment  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
>    #pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

`#pragma comment(lib,"xxx.lib")` is microsoft c/c++ compiler specific.
GCC does not support it.

About

> implicit declaration of function

Simply `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501` before your include, due to

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0501)
void WSAAPI freeaddrinfo (struct addrinfo*);
int WSAAPI getaddrinfo (const char*,const char*,const struct addrinfo*,
                struct addrinfo**);
int WSAAPI getnameinfo(const struct sockaddr*,socklen_t,char*,DWORD,
               char*,DWORD,int);
#else
/* FIXME: Need WS protocol-independent API helpers.  */
#endif
```

in `ws2tcpip.h` file.

Comment: Yes, You should, because of is ignored.

Comment: For the linker error, you have to add `-lws2_32` to the compiler command line.

Comment: @MatteoItalia As shown in post, command used is correct: `gcc -Wall -o "test" "test.c" -lws2_32`

Answer (score 0):

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
is Microsoft speciofic (as LPs answered). It means "link this library." E.g. in case of gcc add this linking request -l (lowercase minus L with name of library) to command line, e.g.
gcc yoursource.c ... -lWs2_32